# protecting my app

Tags: android, opencv, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

I have made a demo app in Android for some people in a far away country. I trust the people - but now we are in disagreement of a contract (luckily, before it is signed) and I might have to exit the project.

The demo app uses OpenCV and some other free libraries.

There's some protection already:

- Major parts of the "secret" algorithm is written in Native C++ code, which is harder to reverse engineer than compiled Java
- It was built in "release" mode, using ProGuard obfuscation and running menu "Build / Build APK(s)". I think it was also "signed" because I have followed these steps https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-auto
- The production system (yet to be developed) will require a backend component generating certain unique strings. I have not given them this part, only a set of example such unique strings. (Actually they could make their own by reverse engineering of the Java parts BUT.. I bet if they are so skilled, they wouldn't need my demo app to begin with...)

I have sent them several earlier APK versions without an "expire date" which I now regret. If they get a new APK which later expires, they could just throw it away and install/run an older version.

Can my app scan their phone looking for older versions of the APK? Then I could make a new "improved version" that refuses to run until all older versions are uninstalled and removed.

(Of course, they could have copies elsewhere but at least it helps.)

Comment: A device can only install one version - that is, the app identifier like com.example.testdrive must be unique. If you have provided apks like com.example.testdrive1, com.example.testdrive2, etc., or com.example.testdrive.v1, com.example.testdrive.v2, etc., then multiple versions can exist.

Comment: To me this seems more of a business question. Unclear what value is of the older versions vs newer versions (with 'expire date') unless newer versions are just cosmetic (and not a code level change like updated API endpoint, data formatting, etc). Even if the client has a MVP that is all that the client has unless they have the source and signing key.

Comment: Well, this is a problem which bugs all of us. Ans the answer unfortunately is: ***There is nothing you can do***: A determined hacker will always find his/her way to your source code. You can make their life **harder**, but not **impossible**.

Comment: @Mick that is true but I meant searching for the APK file. With some luck they only downloaded it to the phones and installed there. The APK files might remain even if the app was installed over the previous version.

Comment: Morrison Change, sure. The last version of mine had really excellent performance and they might use it to demo for financiers without me being in the project. I'd like to prevent that.

Comment: Kling Klang, making their life harder is all I need - if they had so skilled hackers to circumvent everything I try, it would be easier for them to employ said hacker to make an app from scratch instead.